# htaccess não carrega CSS com segundo parâmetro

Tags: htaccess

Olá. Eu tenho quebrado muito a cabeça para tentar solucionar um problema que deveria ser muito simples, mas não está dando certo.

Meu site é navegado da seguinte maneira no htaccess `localhost/ProjetoBusca/index.php?pg=anuncio` sendo substituído por `localhost/ProjetoBusca/anuncio`. Até aqui funciona perfeitamente. O problema é que eu preciso de um GET secundário, onde o ideal seria transformar `localhost/ProjetoBusca/index.php?pg=anuncio&n=354` sendo substituido por `localhost/ProjetoBusca/anuncio/354`

Para isso, no meu htaccess eu desenvolvi:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/(.*)$ index.php?pg=$1&n=$2 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/(.*)/$ index.php?pg=$1&n=$2 [NC]
```

Quando eu trabalho apenas com */anuncio* no site (como citado acima) tudo funciona normal, o problema é que quando eu chamo */anuncio/354* eu consigo pegar o get da variavel n, mas o CSS da página inteira não carrega.
O que pode estar acontecendo?

Segue o código do index.php:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <?php   include("view/header.php"); ?>
    </head>
    <body>      

        <?php      

            include("view/topbar.php");
            include("view/navbar.php");

            if(isset($_GET['pg'])){
                $url = $_GET['pg'];                                     

                if(!file_exists("$url.php")){
                    include("home.php");
                }else{
                    include("$url.php");
                }
            }else{
                include("home.php");
            }

            if(isset($_GET["n"])){
                echo "foi instanciado n: ".$_GET["n"]; //para fins de teste
            }

            include("view/rodape.php");
            include("view/copyright.php");
            include("view/scripts.php");?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

OBS: os include com view/... é porque estão em outra pasta mesmo.

Comment: Acontece porque o link `/anuncio/354` é interpretado como diretórios, e então o css é buscado dentro delas(`/anuncio/354/css/style.css`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bom, esse é um problema bastante comum quando se utiliza `urls amigáveis`, existem diversas formas de soluciona-lo, a mais básica seria requisitar seu css com um link absoluto:

```
<link href="http://www.meusite.com/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Existem formas mais dinâmicas para isso, para obter a url do site:

```
<?php define('SITE_URL', ' http://localhost/ProjetoBusca'); ?>
```

Depois para obter esta url você utilizaria:

```
<link href="<?php echo SITE_URL; ?>/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Você também pode usar `$_SERVER` para buscar esta url:

```
$baseUrl = dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']).'/';
```

Fonte: [stackoverflow em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8350144/seo-friendly-urls-changes-default-directory)

Você também pode usar uma `base tag`:

```
<base href="http://www.meusite.com/" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
```

De qualquer forma você terá que ter um caminho absoluto para requisitar.

Fonte: [http://pumka.net/](http://pumka.net/2009/12/24/seo-friendly-urls-and-relative-links/)

Comment: Deu certo, obrigado!