# Url amigável não aceita a barra após o link

Tags: htaccess

Tenho  no .htaccess o seguinte código:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ categoria.php?key=$1 [NC,L]
```

Funciona perfeitamente, porém quando coloco a barra após o link, ele abre a página sem a formatação CSS, como se estivesse abrindo um novo diretório. Ex.:

**Funciona:**

www.site.com.br/roupas

**Não funciona:**

www.site.com.br/roupas/

Como eu faria para que aceitasse a barra no final do diretório?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [htaccess não carrega CSS com segundo parâmetro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/178207/htaccess-n%c3%a3o-carrega-css-com-segundo-par%c3%a2metro)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se o seu link para o `css` está sendo procurando relativo ao arquivo assim:

```
 href="css/seu_arquivo.css"
```

E seus arquivos estão na pasta raíz do diretório (provavelmente httpdocs ou algo assim) então a busca do caminho do arquivo ocorre da seguinte maneira:

```
httpdocs/css/seu_arquivo.css
```

Acontece que quando você adiciona a barra, o seu arquivo que 'linka' o css entende que você está dentro de uma pasta `roupas/`, logo ele procura assim:

```
httpdocs/roupas/css/seu_arquivo.css
```

Para contornar isso há duas maneiras que conheço, uma é colocando o caminho absoluto com a `url` do seu domínio:

```
href="http://meudominio/css/seu_arquivo.css"
```

Ou a melhor solução que é colocar o caminho subindo uma pasta de nível, caso seus arquivos estejam todos na pasta raíz do seu domínio assim:

```
 href="../css/seu_arquivo.css"
```

Lembrando que isso vale para todos os links de arquivos (`css`/`js`) do seu site e em alguns casos no `src` das imagens.

Comment: Olá Bruno. Na verdade o problema é na url amigável dentro do .htaccess. Pois a página que traz as informações é a categoria.php e o css dela está pegando normalmente.

Comment: Só não funciona se você coloca a barra certo?

Comment: Ajustei meu post, peço desculpas pelo mal entendido.

Comment: KK só pra entender então porque fiquei confuso. O url não abre, ou abre mas somente sem a formatação css?

Comment: A url abre normalmente quando não colocamos a barra, mas quando colocamos, ele interpreta como seu fosse um novo diretório

Comment: Tentou usar a minha solução, ou naõ entendeu algo.

Comment: Acabei de tentar e funcionou. Realmente colocando o caminho absoluto funcionou. Vou marcar como resposta correta. Obrigado Bruno.

Comment: Ainda há a tag `base` do html, não cheguei a testar mas se quiser pode dar uma olhada, parece interessante https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-set-relative-urls-with-the-base-tag--cms-21399